# JRE Redistributable License

Tags: licensing, java, license-key

Is JRE (standard edition) freely redistributable with our commercial application?

Is yes, what license text / note should I look into. Any pointers will greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the JRE from Oracle, you should receive a license, where this all is explained in great detail.